# What are the allowed enumerator initializer types in C++11 scoped enums?

Tags: c++11, gcc, enums, clang, language-lawyer

The following code [compiles cleanly](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/403388866b9d55f4) with GCC 5.2.1

```
enum class some_enum
{
    first = static_cast<some_enum>(1),
};
```

but [fails](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/18c49f574a926dc5) in clang 3.6.2:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++11 enum.cpp  -c
enum.cpp:15:13: error: value of type 'some_enum' is not implicitly convertible to 'int'
    first = static_cast<some_enum>(1),
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

According to my reading of the standard (§7.2, paragraph 5), the enumerator initializer expression must have the same type as the *underlying* type of the enumeration in this case. Which happens to be `int`, not `some_enum`.

So I think clang is correct to reject this, and that this is a bug in GCC. Can anyone with a better understanding of the standard confirm, before I report this as a bug to GCC?

**Edit: to explain my reasoning regarding the standard**

Here is my understanding of 7.2 paragraph 5:

```
Each enumeration defines a type that is different from all other
types. Each enumeration also has an underlying type. The underlying
type can be explicitly specified using enum-base; if not explicitly
specified, the underlying type of a scoped enumeration type is int. In
these cases, the underlying type is said to be fixed.
```

So, since this a scoped enumeration with no explicit enum-base, its underlying type is *fixed* as `int`.

```
Following the closing brace of an enum-specifier, each enumerator
has the type of its enumeration.
```

In other words, outside the `enum` body, an individual enumerator (i.e., named entry within the enum) is has the same type as the entire `enum`.

```
If the underlying type is fixed, the type of each enumerator prior to
the closing brace is the underlying type...
```

Since we're dealing with a scoped enum which always has fixed underlying type, the type of each enum entry *within* the enum body has the same type as the enumeration's underlying type. In this case, within the body, the enumerators have type `int`.

```
...and the constant-expression in the enumerator-definition shall
be a converted constant expression of the underlying type (5.19);
if the initializing value of an enumerator cannot be represented
by the underlying type, the program is ill-formed.
```

In the example case, the initializer has type `some_enum`, which as a C++11 scoped enum cannot be converted to a constant expression of the underlying type without an explicit conversion. So the program is ill-formed.

Comment: That paragraph is referring to a *different* enumeration. E.g.`enum X { a, b, c }; `enum Y { x = a, y = b, z = c };`. Here the type of `a` in the definition of `Y` is the underlying type of `X`.

Comment: The first snippet doesn't [compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9164ae33159ecbae) on gcc 5.2. And what is `same_as_the_second` in the error message?

Comment: @Praetorian Sorry, it was a sloppy copy+paste error resulting from my experimentation. I've corrected the code snippet and error now.

Comment: @KerrekSB What in the paragraph leads you to think that it refers to a different enumeration? I'll edit the question to walk through my parsing of the paragraph, and you can help me identify where I've gone wrong.

Comment: @BobbyMoretti: Is there anything that says that `some_enum` is a complete type before it is finished being defined? My assumption is that it isn't, and that "injected class name" is not a thing in `enum class` definitions. My expectation would actually be that both compilers should reject your code for that reason. It's not just pedantic, the underlying type of the enum may not be known until we know how many enumerators are declared, so it could create a nontrivial difficulty for the compiler.

Comment: @ChrisBeck Good question, and that thought did cross my mind.  However, if that were really a problem, then I don't think something like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e29680cbd68bf1bf) would work.

Comment: @BobbyMoretti: it may just be undefined behavior, iiuc you are often subject to undefined behavior if you use an incomplete type with a standard template. (also a thing that sometimes happens is that symbols that aren't properly defined are treated as `int` by the compiler... so I don't find the fact that that compiles to be particularly compelling) edit: hmm but I do see that you used "-pedantic"... not sure

Comment: @ChrisBeck Agree that just because it works doesn't necessarily mean I'm not invoking undefined behavior.

But incomplete types usually have to do with not knowing the storage layout of an object of that type. This would be a problem with old-style enums, for which the storage size would basically not be known until the enum's closing brace `}` was reached.

Comment: @ChrisBeck From going over the standard, I can't say for sure whether scoped enums are complete types within their bodies. But the standard does say they have a fixed underlying type. And (not the standard, but possibly useful info) cppreference [says](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum) that enum types are fixed as soon as their underlying type is known. For scoped enums, this is always before the `{` is reached.

Comment: I see, I didn't realize this about scoped enums. You are probably right then.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to just be a bug in that version of GCC. It seems to have been fixed in GCC 6. I agree with your reasoning; a value of scoped enumeration type cannot be used where a converted constant expression of an integral type is required.

[CWG 977](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#977), which clarified when enumerations are complete (in particular, an enumeration with a fixed underlying type becomes complete right after its *enum-base*, before any enumerators have been seen), was too late to be included in C++11. But even if we assume that that particular version of GCC was treating the enumeration as incomplete, it was still a bug in that GCC version anyway. I see nothing in the published C++11 standard that justifies treating this case as IFNDR. Though we do often get UB/IFNDR when incomplete types are used in the library, or when incomplete types that later become complete interact with templates.